# View image path in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

My image is located at `/app/assets/images/myfolder/a.png`. I want to return the image url in api. So, how to get this path in controller?
I have tried the below

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.image_path('myfolder/a.png')
ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('myfolder/a.png')
view_context.image_path('myfolder/a.png')
```

but none works .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.image_url('myfolder/a.png')
```

Comment: Does it makes a precompiled path?